# Trying to install an initalize HTML snippet within a PHP variable

Tags: php, wordpress, initialization, code-snippets

I'm trying to get a snippet to initialize on every page but it requires a PHP variable to pull in the correct information. How would I write the code - I currently have the following but it will not initialize correctly. When I pull out the php variable it won't pull in the specific metadata I need.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {

  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    return;
  }
  

  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
  $visitor="";$account="";

  if($uuid = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'uuid', true )){ $visitor.="id: '" . $uuid . "',";}
 echo "

<script>
  (function(apiKey){

    (**redacted**;

    X.initialize({

      visitor: {

        ". $visitor ."

      },

      account: {

        id: '" . $corpID . "',
        
        ". $account ."

      }

    })

  })('redacted');

</script>";
} );
?>`
```

The script buried inside is clearly not functioning and I don't know what the issue is. I am not strong in development and trying to figure this out.

Comment: Open the browser's development tools.  Are there any errors on the development console?  In the page source, what is the resulting JavaScript code being created here?  Is it what you expect?

Comment: On the development tools it is not showing the script portion as green it all shows in red indicating there is an error

Comment: And what is that JavaScript code?  Does it match what you expect?  What is the error?

Comment: The Javascript seems to work as it is getting the metadata from a plugin management system to feed it into the snippet that needs to be initialized. The part that does not seem to function is the initialized code. For some reason it does not initialize correctly. I am thinking it has to do with the  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() and then everything that follows the echo.

Comment: If I don't have the top PHP code (written by someone else) it initializes correctly, but doesn't bring in the metadata that matches the logged-in user. Should that PHP follow the initialize script instead?

Comment: I am seeing this error in the console: ?logged_in_as_user=true:325 Uncaught ReferenceError: active is not defined
    at ?logged_in_as_user=true:325:14
    at ?logged_in_as_user=true:331:5

Comment: And what is the exact JavaScript code which produces that error?  It sounds like you're trying to use a variable called `active` which wasn't defined anywhere.  Were you intending to use such a variable?  If so, where do you expect it to be defined?  If not, why is it there?

Comment: That may have been the ticket!! It looks like removing that one line of code is allowing everything to initialize.